# Google Maps Javascript - unable to load

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am a beginner to javascript and am trying to load a simple Google Map in my browser (firefox). However, the map does not load.

Below is my html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Can you guess the Country?</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key={MY_API_KEY}&sensor=true"></script>
  <script src="mapGame.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="map">

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the linked mapGame.js:

```
var map;

function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,          
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions);
      }
      google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: "Does not load" is a little vague. Are you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: Did you include the key? Did you specify height and width of your map?

Comment: If I use this definition of the "map" div it displays for me locally `<div id="map" style="height:500px; width:600px;">`

Answer (score 0):

probably has to do with the height of the `div#map`, the map is there but you just don't see it.

```
<head>
  <style>
    #map {
      height:500px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```